# how to install windows 7 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS via virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, software-installation, error-handling

i have tried to install windows 7 via virtual box but it cannot be done when i try to open it it shows this error[image]

i would like to install windows 7 via a cd so can anyone help me to get it installed

Comment: solution is in your error report. Just install vbox extension pack.

Comment: how to get it done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install corresponding Virtual Box extension pack for your Virtualbox from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: canyou give the same answer but in terminal form